# Zebra Device-TC75x- Android 8.1-Bar-code Scan Issue

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

We have build App on Zebra devices which scan the barcode and based the scan data we do the API calling.
But in recent update in Android 8.1, we are able to detected the on press event and key code. In Android 6.0 it was 103(R1 button in Android) Keycode.

```java
@Override public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == 103) {
     for (final Listener listener : listeners) {
         new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 listener.didCodeScanned();
             }
         }, 800);
     }
 }
 return false; 
}
```

If anyone know the event for scan button then please let us know.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Hi, why do you insist on using the [zebra] tag? Have you read its description and what it is intended to be used for?

Comment: the issue is related to Zebra devices only.

Comment: The [zebra] tag is only for JavaScript library “Zebra“, not for devices from Zebra.com

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remap keys using the Key Mapping feature on the device (see page 88 of the integrator guide, https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/mobile-computers/tc70x/tc70x-75x-android-81-ig-en.pdf) and remap the scan button to 103.  I can't explain why the behaviour differs for you between Marshmallow and Oreo

Comment: I have not done as you told but using factory reset it works fine now. Thank you for response